# Replacing options on <select> dynamically from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In a bespoke shopping cart, I pull from my database a list of options that a particular product has. The number of these options can vary by product.
I then turn that list of options into a JavaScript array.

An example with 3 options:

```json
{"Small":{"Super":{"Pack":"parta","Case":"parte"},"Maxi":{"Pack":"partb","Case":"partf"}},"Large":{"Super":{"Pack":"partc","Case":"partg"}},"X Large":{"Maxi":{"Pack":"partd"}}}
```

Using the above, I would now like to generate an HTML select field, listing all the "first" options:

```html
<select>
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="X Large">X Large</option>
</select>
```

Once the user has selected the first option, I then need another `<select>` box to then load with options that are available for their selection. So, if they selected "Small" from above, the new select box would be:

```html
<select>
<option value="Super">Super</option>
<option value="Maxi">Maxi</option>
</select>
```

Finally, when they select from this list, a 3rd select box loads in the final options, along with the part numbers as values:

```html
<select>
<option value="parta">Pack</option>
<option value="parte">Case</option>
</select>
```

The number of options can vary, from zero to 4. But, each time when options are available, I need to pull the part number based on the users selection. The part number doesn't necessarily need to be the value of the last select, it can be pushed to a new hidden variable.

I can achieve this using ajax, by making an ajax call every time a selection is chosen, but can it be done via JavaScript / jQuery, without having to make ajax calls, given that the array is on the page and available to use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As your question is written, it's not really appropriate for this forum. You've posted your requirements, but we do expect that users will do their research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here as we are not a tutorial site. When you do post, we expect that you'll post your attempt along with a specific question about what problem you are having.

Comment: This is a common pattern known as dependent combo boxes or dependent drop downs.  Should help in searching. Basically you need break your data up into arrays at each level, and be able to choose which array to show based on what is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dynamically create the `select` element, also determine which "node" in your tree structure goes with that element, and use it to:

- add a default "Please select..." option to the `select` element
- populate the `select` element further with the real options
- determine the deeper node when an option is selected (also when the initial selection is made when the element is created), and use it to create the next `select` element with the same function
- This cascade stops when the deeper node does not exist (when "Please select..." is selected) or it happens to be a string and not an object.

Here is some code for inspiration:

```js
let optionTree = {"Small":{"Super":{"Pack":"parta","Case":"parte"},"Maxi":{"Pack":"partb","Case":"partf"}},"Large":{"Super":{"Pack":"partc","Case":"partg"}},"X Large":{"Maxi":{"Pack":"partd"}}};

let container = document.querySelector("#container");

addSelector(optionTree);

function addSelector(node) {
    let select = document.createElement("select");
    // Start with the default option:
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Please select...";
    select.add(option);
    for (let key in node) { // Populate the select element
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = key;
        option.text = key;
        select.add(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(select); // Add it to the page

    function change() {
        // Remove select elements that come after the selection
        while (select.nextElementSibling) {
            select.nextElementSibling.remove();
        }
        let key = select.value;
        if (node[key] && typeof node[key] !== "string") {
            addSelector(node[key]); // Create the next select element(s)
        }
    }
    // Call the above function whenever a selection is made
    select.addEventListener("change", change);
    change(); // ... and also call it now
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution @trincot. I'm a novice at javascript and this all seems pretty easy to follow. Just one question. How can I add a "Please Select" to each dropdown? I tried adding:
`let initoption = document.createElement("option");
 initoption.value = "";
 initoption.text = "Please Select";
 select.add(initoption);`
But that seems to break things. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated the answer to take that requirement into account.

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you so much @trincot. I've managed to tweak it to fully fit my requirements! Once I have enough reputation I'll upvote your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Done. Many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the three select elements in the DOM, you can populate the first select, and add a change event listener to both the first and second to achieve this. Try this

```js
let $s1 = document.querySelector('#select-1');
let $s2 = document.querySelector('#select-2');
let $s3 = document.querySelector('#select-3');

let object = {"Small":{"Super":{"Pack":"parta","Case":"parte"},"Maxi":{"Pack":"partb","Case":"partf"}},"Large":{"Super":{"Pack":"partc","Case":"partg"}},"X Large":{"Maxi":{"Pack":"partd"}}};

// add options to first select
$s1.innerHTML = '<option></option>'; // empty select
Object.keys(object).forEach(val => $s1.append(new Option(val, val))); // append children
$s1.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // trigger change event

// listen to change event on first select/get options for second select
$s1.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    $s2.innerHTML = '<option></option>'; // empty select

    // append children
    Object.keys(object[e.target.value] ?? []).forEach(val => {
        $s2.appendChild(new Option(val, val));
    });

    // trigger change event
    $s2.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});

// listen to change event on second select/get options for third select
$s2.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    $s3.innerHTML = '<option></option>'; // empty select

    // append children
    Object.entries(object[$s1.value]?.[e.target.value] ?? []).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        $s3.appendChild(new Option(key, val));
    });
});
```

```css
select {min-width:80px}
```

```html
<select id="select-1"></select>
<select id="select-2"></select>
<select id="select-3"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ruleboy21 I went with the other solution, but I appreciate the help regardless.